# If URL Changes Dynamically with AJAX, how could I add something to the Page with AJAX or PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic

I have a filter in side my website sidebar, that whenever I click on one of the options. It changes the URL to something like this: `/index.php?bfilter=45-Color[Blue]` and all the products (this is a store in opencart), are changed as well.

All that is great, but I wanted to add something on a different part of the page. So whenever the url changes that it would add something to the page in the area I specify. So I decided to use this php:

```
  <?php if(isset($_GET['bfilter'])){ ?>
  // my divs here
  <?php } ?>
```

This works great and all for if you refresh the page and it is set. But since the URL is being updated with ajax, the page doesnt reload, and therefore it doesnt show my div.

So my question. How can I use AJAX to show something if the URL is updated?

Comment: the urls is being changed with pushstate, so your best bet is to put your code into the part that changes the urls or attach your evento to window.onhashchange

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls shouldn't affect the current location url. In fact, if the location url is changed it would trigger a reload, which would make ajax pointless.

You can check the current url at any time with the JS variable `location.href`. But if your php snippet doesn't work, then perhaps your ajax call isn't actually changing the location, but instead using [HTML5 history API](http://html5demos.com/history) to simulate the behavior.

If that's the case, then you should check for the JS variable `history.state.url` on the callback of your ajax function.

```
console.log('Current Browse location', location.href);
console.log('History API location', history.state.url);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is request that page via an XMLHttpRequest with the appropriate URL. See example below. **Disclaimer**: This is just an example and doesn't do any validation, and should not be used for production!

```
<div 
  id="filter" 
  data-filter-key="bfilter" 
  data-filter-value="45-Color[Blue]">Filter Me</div>

document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var key = target.getAttribute('data-filter-key');
  var value = target.getAttribute('data-filter-value');
  var url = '/index.php?' + key + '=' + value;
  // do your ajax request with the url, and then inject the response into the DOM
});
```